# Sharepoint Authentication with ms office

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, authentication

I just encountered an unexpected behaviour of SP online working with the local ms office.

It looks like if someone opens a document (i.e. docx), the local word instance doesn't care about the user logged in in SP online.

Let's say there are 2 users, Marc and Tom. Marc uploads a document and restricts the access to readonly for Tom. Now Tom only can read the document, even in MS Word. If he loggs in as Marc and tries to open the document, I would expect the document to be editable. In MS Word online it is, but as soon as Tom (now logged in as Marc) opens the document in MS Word on his computer, it's readonly again.

I suppose that's as designed. But does anyone know the technical background of this? How does SP authenticate users against the local MS-Office?

Comment: Which version of Office do you use? There have been several changes in the last versions.

Comment: Office 2016 respectively Office 365

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a perfect answer, because i do not have a Office 2016 klick-to-run installation for testing. But i would have a look at the keyword "Office 365 modern authentication". Maybe you will find your answer there.

Some links:

[How modern authentication works for Office 2013 and Office 2016 client apps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-modern-authentication-works-for-Office-2013-and-Office-2016-client-apps-e4c45989-4b1a-462e-a81b-2a13191cf517)

[Updated Office 365 modern authentication](https://blogs.office.com/2015/11/19/updated-office-365-modern-authentication-public-preview/)

Have another idea: [Maybe there is an account stored in Windows' Credential Manager](http://windowsitpro.com/microsoft-office/wrong-account-used-when-connection-office-365-applications)